# Need advice with a model - should I choose has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blog with posts and tags. I want to add email notification functionality - users can subscribe to one or more tags and receive email notifications when new posts are added.

Currently I have a Tag model.

There will be a Subscriber model (containing the user's email)

Do you think I also need a Subscription table where Subscriber and Tag are joined?
.. or I can skip it and directly link Subscriber with Tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one subscriber to be subscribed to multiple tags, you need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between subscribers and tags.

To accomplish this, you'll need to create a so-called join table:

```
create_table :subscribers_tags, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :subscriber, :tag
end
```

This will create a table without an `id` column, but with `subscriber_id` and `tag_id`. Then, you specify the relationship:

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers
end
```

You can then access and manipulate the relationship in your code:

```
Subscriber.first.tags # => [<Tag>, <Tag>, ...]
Tag.first.subscribers # => [<Subscriber>, ...]

Subscriber.find(123).tags << Tag.find(321)
Tag.find(321).subscribers << Subscriber.new(...)
```

For a full list of methods you can perform on the associations, see [this section of the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thank you vonconrad.